# Mobile website stretched

Tags: css, mobile, web, mobile-safari

http://demo.dev.rbmleads.com/personalloan/v10/

I made a mobile version of a form for work but can't figure out why it's stretched out like this. It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

but instead it looks like this:

[image]

I thought it was a stray element in there with a set with but all the elements are set to auto or a %. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: sorry about that, let me update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set the meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width" />
```

this will make your 100% a little closer to 100%

there are a few other parameters you can set like initial zoom and heights but I think this width will solve your problem

EDIT: One additional thing you can try is to query width and set the font size

example of some LESS:

```
html,body{
    font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;

    @media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
}
```

Basically this sets your base font to 16px on a phone and 11px on a desktop.

Comment: Hey Dan, yeah it was. I also added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">` so that the user couldn't zoom in as it was already the perfect size. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Are you declaring the `viewport` meta tag?

Add this to your `<head>`:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

If you need to disable zooming:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is just the resolution try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> in Firefox. Also set `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and play with the scale.

Your sandbox is not reachable, which makes it hard to find the issue.